# Spring 4 MVC - Rest service - use default values in beans

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-4

I am using `Spring 4.1.4` and implementing a simple `REST` service. I do have a `POST` method which gets a `Person` object as request.

```
@ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.CREATED)
@RequestMapping(value = "", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/json", consumes = "application/json")
public void add(@Valid @RequestBody Person oPerson) throws Exception {
    //do the things
}
```

**Bean:**

```
public class Person {

    public Person(){ }

    private String firstname;

    private String lastname;

    private Integer activeState;

    //getter+setter
}
```

My question is - is there a possibility to set a default value for the properties in the bean. Something like this:

```
@Value(default=7)
private Integer activeState;
```

I know when using the `@RequestParam` annotation in a `@RestController` methode it is possible to set a default value with `@RequestParam(value="activeState", required=false, defaultValue="2")` but is there a possibility to do a similar thing on class level?

Comment: when should the default value been applied: if the parameter is not in the request at all, of if the parameter is null/empty?

Comment: Simply just declare a value for the integer field in the class: `private Integer activeState = 2;` Or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: @Ralph good question - in both cases: not present and null or empty

Comment: @RobinJonsson - I also thought about that, but I don't know if that is the best solution, I use the object also as a persistence object for a database...

Comment: @K.E. I've always had the mindset of not using my entities all the way to the front-end. However, setting the default value like this works as long as the incoming object hasn't overwritten that field. Isn't that what you were looking for?

Comment: @RobinJonsson yes, you are right with the entities which shouldn't be used but in this specific case it is ok for me. And ok, you persuaded me - if you post this solution as answer, i will accept.

Comment: Or just add a method annotated with `@ModelAttribute` which constructs a `Person` object and sets the default values. That way you only have defaults in the web layer and not tied into your `Person` object.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your Person class is not really a spring bean. It is simply a class whose parameters are set when you make a call to your application endpoint due to the `@RequestBody` annotation. The parameters which are not in the body of your call will simply not get binded so to solve your problem you can do this:

1. Set default values for your person class like this (`toString()` is overridden for convenience:

   ```
   public class Person {

       public Person() {
       }

       private String firstName = "default";
       private String lastName = "default";
       private Integer activeState = 7;

       public String getFirstName() {
           return firstName;
       }

       public String getLastName() {
           return lastName;
       }

       public Integer getActiveState() {
           return activeState;
       }

       @Override
       public String toString() {
           return "Person{" +
                   "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                   ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                   ", activeState=" + activeState +
                   '}';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Perform the request to your endpoint, for example with this json data:

   ```
   {
       "firstName": "notDefault"
   }
   ```
3. If you print out the person object in your controller, you'll notice that the firstName got the non-default value while others are default:

   ```
   public void add(@Valid @RequestBody Person oPerson) {
       System.out.println(oPerson);
   }
   ```

Console output:
`Person{firstName='notDefault', lastName='default', activeState=7}`

Comment: Great, and what if your dto's are immutable? Also I don't believe it's the responsibility of dto object to dictate the behavior or controller endpoint

Comment: @Ben if they're immutable, then handle default value assignment in the controller method. That is, check which values are missing and make a new copy of your immutable object with them being assigned.

Comment: This is not a good case when we have the same DTO for multiple endpoints. Some endpoints would like to have different default values or no default values at all.

Answer (score -1):

Adding to @Edd answer, ***if you want to override the default values from the input***, then we have to annotate the bean with [`@JsonAutoDetect`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonAutoDetect.html), as follows:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonAutoDetect.Visibility;

@JsonAutoDetect(fieldVisibility = Visibility.ANY, getterVisibility = Visibility.NONE, setterVisibility = Visibility.NONE)
public class Person {

    public Person() {
    }

    private String firstName = "default";
    private String lastName = "default";
    private Integer activeState = 7;

    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public Integer getActiveState() {
        return activeState;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person{" +
                "firstName='" + firstName + '\'' +
                ", lastName='" + lastName + '\'' +
                ", activeState=" + activeState +
                '}';
    }
}
```