# Why does the received entity in my @RestController is setting value to null not to default

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-rest

I am using :

- spring data rest
- lombok

When I receive my entity in my controller

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
Long create(@RequestBody Blog blog) {
  blogService.insert(blog);
  return blog.getId();
}
```

I only set the blog name, however, `Blog.java` contains default values:

```
private Boolean isDisabled = false;
private Boolean canCreateTags = true;
private Boolean canCreateCategories = true;
private Boolean hasRss = false;
```

This is the request body of my request :

{"organization":{"id":"1"},"description":"test"}

All the unsend values appear to be `null`.

However when I use the `BlogDTO` instead of `Blog`:

```
@PostMapping
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
Long create(@RequestBody BlogDTO blog) {
  blogService.insert(blog);
  return blog.getId();
}
```

All the values are set with defaults.

- Why is the instance not created with my defaults?
- Why is the DTO instance created with defaults?

Comment: Please mark the answer as right if it was helpful to you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overriding the toString method of Blog.java with default values should solve this problem like below

```
public class Blog {

private Boolean isDisabled = false;
private Boolean canCreateTags = true;
private Boolean canCreateCategories = true;
private Boolean hasRss = false;

    @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "Blog{" +
                    "isDisabled='" + isDisabled + '\'' +
                    ", canCreateTags='" + canCreateTags + '\'' +
                    ", canCreateCategories=" + canCreateCategories +
                    '}';
        }
    }
```

Please refer this question and answer as a reference [Spring 4 MVC - Rest service - use default values in beans](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35499575/spring-4-mvc-rest-service-use-default-values-in-beans)

Answer (score 0):

if you want to have default value you need to set explicitly while sending to post call body

Comment: This is not completely true, I've added an example with a DTO object that does the job